# ORDER BY after mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']) erroring

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select, sql-order-by

I am trying to add the "ORDER BY" code into an existing system that by default is posting new topics at the bottom, not the top, I found another article on here where this worked for someone..

```
$sql = "SELECT topic_id, topic_subject, topic_date, topic_cat
    FROM topics WHERE topic_cat = " . mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']) .   "ORDER BY topic_date DESC;";
```

I'm not getting any syntax errors, but the category page is returning

"The topics could not be displayed, please try again later."

I didn't know the rules on post in old "answered" questions so I thought it would be best to put my problem separate as the above code worked for someone else and fixed their issue.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a space before `ORDER BY`:

```
.   "ORDER BY
```

should be:

```
.   " ORDER BY
```

Echoing out your query or using `mysql_error()` would have caught this for you.

Comment: That did it! sometimes all you need is a fresh set of eyes on the problem to find what you're doing wrong, thanks!